# Can we cancel common factors in numerator and denominator while applying L Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I was evaluating the following limit given below:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^3\ln(x)}{(x^2+1)^2}
$$

As this expression is of the form $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$, it applied L Hospital rule which gave me:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x^2\ln(x)+x^2}{4x(x^2+1)}
$$

This expression is again of $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ form. So I can apply L Hospital rule once again.
Now $x$ is a common factor both in numerator and denominator.
My question is whether I can cancel this common factor before applying L Hospital rule. After cancellation of this common factor $x$, we are left with the following expression:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x\ln(x)+x}{4(x^2+1)}
$$

This new expression obtained after cancelling common factors is again of the form $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$.

So my question is whether we are allowed to cancel common factors in this manner or does it impact the value of the limit and hence not permissible.

Please suggest.

Comment: You can cancel the common factor, as the new expression is equal to the previous one. For example, when you encounter $\lim_{x\to \infty}{x\over x^2}$ do not apply Hospital rule, but cancel the common factor.

Comment: A quicker method would be to write $x^2+1$ as $x^2$ in the denominator as x tends to infinty..and then apply lhospital

Comment: @RamanujanXXV I agree that you can do this, but it requires a smidgen of justification.  The justification is that you're multiplying the original expression by $\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}$, which has limit $1$ as $x \to \infty$.